# wait for command line program execution before issuing new action in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I am pretty new to AppleScript. I need a script that opens 3 iTerm tabs and executes 3 command line programs respectively. The first program terminates, while the last 2 run indeterminately.

Here is what I have:

```
tell application "iTerm"
    activate
    set next to (make new terminal)
    tell next
        activate current session
        launch session "Default Session"
        tell the last session
            set name to "vagrant-db"
            write text "cd ~/Workspace/vagrant-db; vagrant up"
        end tell

        launch session "Default Session"
        tell the last session
            set name to "next/core"
            write text "cd ~/Workspace/next"
            write text "/usr/local/bin/sbt \"project core\" \"run\""
        end tell

        launch session "Default Session"
        tell the last session
            set name to "next/web"
            write text "cd ~/Workspace/next"
            write text "/usr/local/bin/sbt \"project web\" \"~re-start\""
        end tell

    end tell
end tell
```

Problem is I need to wait for the first command line operation to end (vagrant booting up) before issuing the second and third. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved with something like

```
            --first program exec

            set a to 0
            repeat until (a = 1)
                if (text of current session contains "ready") then
                    set a to 1
                end if
            end repeat

            --second program exec
            --third program exec
```

Comment: So you used "something like" the above answer to read the text? Using that syntax I keep getting `The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error.` when I try to use it. Can you post the text check in context please?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is possible, but maybe using "do shell script" command from applescript instead, e.g.

```
set response to do shell script "ls"
```

will return the contents of the root folder.

Another way (but a very ugly one) is to use 'delay'. E.g.

```
delay 5
```

Will delay for 5 seconds

Comment: `do shell script` seems to be blocking.. however it does not give me any output on the terminal, which is not really ideal.. is there a way to repeat something like "read last line on terminal"? so that when I read something like "success" I can go on with starting the 2 programs..

Answer (score 1):

Rusty's answer worked for me.  I'm adding this answer to provide detail requested by fusio (sorry, I'd rather have provided this as comment, but comments require more reputation points than adding a new answer).

Rusty's answer requires already being in the context of talking to the current window.

```
on wait_for(str)
    tell application "iTerm"
        tell current window
            set a to 0
            repeat until (a = 1)
                if (text of current session contains str) then
                    set a to 1
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end wait_for
```

Then, in your code, call:

```
my wait_for("Provisioners marked to run always will still run.")
```

The above argument occurs later than "ready".

This is still plenty ugly, but it works.